# How does torrenting affect the browsing speed?

Tags: networking, internet, speed, bittorrent

I am unclear how does the torrent download affects the speed test.  I am on a 5 Mbps line, When I download my torrent file at the speed of 300KB/s ( big B), then the speed test speed ([www.speedtest.net](http://www.speedtest.net/))drops to 2.5Mbps ( small b).  Two questions arise:

1. It seems that the torrent speed is not optimized because It should download at 600KB/s ( consumes around `600K*8=4.8Mbps`), and leave speed test speed to be minimum. Am I right?
2. Separate question: is the relationship between torrent speed and the browsing speed expressed in the below equation correct?

> total speed given by ISP=speed used by torrent+browsing speed+network overhead?

Note: The torrent file I download has more than 2000 peers, so lacking of peer is not the problem.

Comment: Torrent is peer to peer connection. If your peer sources bandwidth (combined) only reach to 300KB/s, then there is not much you can do until there are more peers providing more bandwidth to you. The rest of the bandwidth are then available for you to use. If you want to ensure you can get the full bandwidth when downloading torrent, try a torrent with over 5000 peers (or even over 1000 seeds if any - which is usually newly released stuff). You can saturate your whole bandwidth and get maximum speed. To add to your calculation + Network overhead.

Comment: @Darius, the torrent I have has a lot of peer, number in thousands.

Comment: @Graviton You're just not downloading from all of them. They might be busy uploading to others. // Could you please be more specific on what the question here is?

Comment: @DanielBeck, question edited, hopefully is more clear now

Answer (score 0):

Your torrent client should have an option for maximum connections per torrent. Make sure this is not too high or too low (keep between 10-20 for 5Mbps line).

As Darius points out, the peers you are connecting to might not be uploading fast enough to max out your connection, and/or they are connected to other people and won't connect to you.

To maximize your download speed, ensure that your ports are properly forwarded -- google your router model number and `port forwarding tutorial` to find help online in setting this up so more peers can connect to you.